# Adding link to Web Reference from a Project - ChannelBase not found

Tags: silverlight, wcf, web-services

I am building a Silverlight app. As I have classes to be consumed by Silverlight and .NET modules, I have created a Silverlight project with all the classes in it and then, a .NET project linking('Add Link') to the classes in Silverlight project. This way, I have one class file compiled separately as Silverlight and .NET assemblies. I want to replicate the same for web service references. Meaning, I have web references in the Silverlight project. I am trying to 'Add Link' to reference.cs from Silverlight project into the .NET project. When I compile the .NET project, the ChannelBase class doesn't get resolved it seems due to disparity in definition of the class in Silverlight and .NET framework libraries. This results in compilation error stating unresolved ChannelBase. Sounds like a dead end to me. Do you see a way around this problem?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Note: If you just gotta get it to compile (ie for unit tests and you'll never actually use the WCF service), create a non-namespaced class in your assembly (ChannelBase<T> where T : class), and add the constructor and BeginInvoke/EndInvoke. I also had to add System.ServiceModel.Channels.IHttpCookieContainerManager

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not possible. Both proxies are completely different: one of them is synchronous while the other one is not.

The best thing you can do is to share the service defined classes, not the whole proxy. Just create those classes beforehand, use "Add as link" to reuse them in both projects, and then when you add the service reference, mark the option "Reuse types in referenced assemblies".

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else stumbles on this.  I had a similar problem.  I was generating the proxy using `slsvcutil.exe` and trying to compile it for .net and monotouch.  I kept getting `ChannelBase not found`.  Which made no sense at all. Finally I commented out the `CookieContainer` property in the proxy client class and low and behold the compile error went away and the proxy works for monotouch.